# NextAuth.js - API Handler should not return a value, received obect <<-- how do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next-auth, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to build an e-commerce website using React and Mongo Atlas. My Google auth was working fine and then I added the DB credentials and its stopped working, asking me to try another email when I use Google to log in. I'm getting this error in the terminal...

`[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.asaetgi.mongodb.net { message: 'querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.asaetgi.mongodb.net', stack: 'Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.asaetgi.mongodb.net\n' +         '    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:217:17)',    name: 'Error' } [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.asaetgi.mongodb.net Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.asaetgi.mongodb.net at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:217:17) {         name: 'GetUserByAccountError', code: 'ENOTFOUND' } API handler should not return a value, received object.`

I've made sure my IP address is in the cluster. The only thing I can think is that I've used my dev email account for Mongo and I've used just my normal gmail for Google cloud credentials, but I didn't think that would matter..... Here's my code

[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from '@/lib/mongodb'

```
export default NextAuth({
   providers: [
     GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    }),

],

adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
})
```

/lib/mongo.db

```
`import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}
```

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {

```
if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
}
clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
```

} else {

```
client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
clientPromise = client.connect();
```

}

export default clientPromise;`

The github is here >> https://github.com/hannahf86/pfMusicPublishing-admin

Thanks in advance!